# Electronics Problem

Tags: optimization, systems-of-equations

I have the following circuit for which I need to calculate the values of **R1** & **R2** to satisfy several conditions.

**Circuit:**

[image: Circuit]

**Conditions:**

[image: Conditions]

**Thermistor values:**

Thermistor value is non-linear and is dependent on temperature. The value can be considered infinite when it is disconnected from the circuit.

[image: Thermistor Values]

**Equation:**

[image: Equation]

Basically, **VR2** should be less than **2.25** when the value of **RNTC** is **5k**, and greater than **4** when the value of **RNTC** is **20k**. When the **RNTC** is infinite, it should be between the **2.25** and **4**.

How can this problem be solved? Is it even possible?

Comment: Should $k$ be interpreted as $\mathrm{k\Omega}$?

Comment: Aren't these problems much suited for [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: @Algebrology. I would say that this is a border case. It's the math that is the problem here, not the physics.

Comment: It is fairly easy to see that if $R_{NTC}$ increases, the combined resistance of $R_{NTC}$ and $R_2$ increases, which increases $V_{R_2}$. So as $R_{NTC}$  increases from $5k$ to $20k$ to $\infty$, the voltage will increase from less than $2.25$ to greater then $4$ to something even greater than that. It cannot end up being smaller than $4$.

Comment: @md2perpe even if math is the problem, you can still ask it on physics stack exchange. That's not a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing
$$
V_{R_2}(40) = \frac{R_\parallel(40)}{R_1+R_\parallel(40)} E
,\quad\quad
V_{R_2}(10) = \frac{R_\parallel(10)}{R_1+R_\parallel(10)} E
$$
and solving both these equations for $R_1$ I get
$$
\left(\frac{E}{V_{R_2}(40)} - 1\right) R_\parallel(40) 
= R_1
= \left(\frac{E}{V_{R_2}(10)} - 1\right) R_\parallel(10)
$$
from which I then get
$$
\frac{R_\parallel(10)}{R_\parallel(40)}
= \frac{\frac{E}{V_{R_2}(40)} - 1}{\frac{E}{V_{R_2}(10)} - 1}
$$
The values on the right hand side are given, and I will denote this quotient with $\lambda$.

Now,
$$
\frac{R_\parallel(10)}{R_\parallel(40)}
= \frac{\frac{R_2 R_{\text{ntc}}(10)}{R_2+ R_{\text{ntc}}(10)}}{\frac{R_2 R_{\text{ntc}}(40)}{R_2+ R_{\text{ntc}}(40)}}
= \frac{R_{\text{ntc}}(10)}{R_{\text{ntc}}(40)} 
  \frac{R_2 + R_{\text{ntc}}(40)}{R_2+ R_{\text{ntc}}(10)}
$$
so we shall solve
$$
\frac{R_{\text{ntc}}(10)}{R_{\text{ntc}}(40)} \frac{R_2 + R_{\text{ntc}}(40)}{R_2+ R_{\text{ntc}}(10)} = \lambda
$$
for $R_2.$

Doing this I get
$$
%\\
%\frac{R_2 + R_{\text{ntc}}(40)}{R_2+ R_{\text{ntc}}(10)} = \lambda %\frac{R_{\text{ntc}}(40)}{R_{\text{ntc}}(10)} \\
%R_2 + R_{\text{ntc}}(40) = \lambda \frac{R_{\text{ntc}}(40)}{R_{\text{ntc}}(10)} \left(R_2+ R_{\text{ntc}}(10)\right) \\
%\left( 1 - \lambda \frac{R_{\text{ntc}}(40)}{R_{\text{ntc}}(10)} \right) R_2 
%= \lambda \frac{R_{\text{ntc}}(40)}{R_{\text{ntc}}(10)} R_{\text{ntc}}(10) - R_{\text{ntc}}(40)
%= \lambda R_{\text{ntc}}(40) - R_{\text{ntc}}(40) = (\lambda-1) R_{\text{ntc}}(40) \\
R_2 = \frac{(\lambda-1) R_{\text{ntc}}(40)}{1 - \lambda \frac{R_{\text{ntc}}(40)}{R_{\text{ntc}}(10)}}
.
$$
Finally we can calculate $R_1$:
$$
R_1 = \left(\frac{E}{V_{R_2}(10)} - 1\right) R_\parallel(10)
= \left(\frac{E}{V_{R_2}(10)} - 1\right) \frac{R_2 R_{\text{ntc}}(10)}{R_2+R_{\text{ntc}}(10)}
.
$$

Try first with $V_{R_2}(10)=4\ \mathrm{V}$ and $V_{R_2}(40)=2.25\ \mathrm{V}$.

Comment: Perfect, and a reminder that I need a refresher course in math! :)